# ¿Como traer solo un resultado de la tabla con la que se hace un JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las tablas siguientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podrían ayudarme en crear una consulta para para obtener el precio actual de cada producto? que seria el ultimo registro de la tabla `producto_precio`
Cada producto tiene un precio pero se guarda el historial de precios de cada producto en la tabla `producto_precio` y al generar una consulta me trae datos repetidos.

```
SELECT * 
FROM producto JOIN producto_precio ON producto.id = producto_precio.id_producto 
ORDER BY producto.id
```

genera esta tabla pero solo quiero el resultado con el precio actual q seria el ultimo registro de la tabla `producto_precio`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria el resultado q busco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo conseguí con esta consulta pero cuando se trata de muchos registros el servidor básico de hostgator tarda unos segundos en procesar la consulta

```
SELECT producto.*,
(SELECT producto_precio.id FROM producto_precio WHERE producto_precio.id_producto = producto.id ORDER BY producto_precio.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS id_precio,
(SELECT producto_precio.precio FROM producto_precio WHERE producto_precio.id_producto = producto.id ORDER BY producto_precio.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS precio
FROM producto
```

Una disculpa si no me exprese bien
Los datos de las tablas son los siguientes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí pongo la consulta q solo me retorna un resultado, lo que puse en amarillo es porque la tabla de producto el atributo "id" se llama `id` y no `id_producto`, error mío

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La consulta se puede hacer pero te doy un consejo mejor. No es mala idea guardar un histórico de precios, pero sí es malo tener que consultar la tabla de precios para conocer el precio actual. Lo ideal es que el precio actual lo guardes en un campo de la tabla producto, así el rendimiento será mucho mejor, y dejas la tabla producto_precio sólo para lo que es: un histórico de precios. Ah, y no estaría mal añadir a esa tabla el momento (datetime) en que se registra cada precio.

Comment: De acuerdo con las recomendaciones de @JoséCarlosPHP . Otra opción es tener un campo adicional en la tabla producto_precio en el que puedas identificar el precio actual, como un estado. De este modo sólo tendrías que agregar en el `JOIN` una condición `AND producto_precio.estado = 1`

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP si pensé en eso, pero, no lo hice de esa manera porque hay cosas q cambian de precio de un día para otro, entonces pedidos de hoy tienen un precio y pedidos de mañana tendrán otro precio. y en las ordenes de compra se guarda el id del precio del día que se pago, es por eso el historial de precios

Comment: Una buena idea es guardar el precio en las líneas de pedido. Es como se suele hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER()`. Por ejemplo:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT p.*,
    pp.id as pp_id, pp.id_producto, pp.precio
    row_number() over(partition by p.id order by pp.id_precio desc) as rn
  FROM producto p
  JOIN producto_precio pp ON p.id = pp.id_producto 
) x
where rn = 1
ORDER BY id
```

La otra alternativa típica es usar un join lateral.

Comment: Lo estaré intentado

Comment: wow, esto es lo q estaba buscando, rendimiento y velocidad. muchas gracias, he logrado lo q quería con tu consulta sql, pase de 3 segundos a milésimas de segundos, muchas gracias en verdad

Answer (score 0):

No es muy recomendable depender de lo que parece ser un autonumérico como `precio.id`, normalmente el `id` más alto es el más nuevo, pero la base de datos solo garantiza que este dato no se repita, no que tenga cierto orden (aunque en la práctica lo tenga). Lo ideal es que en la tabla precios, manejes un número de versión controlado por la aplicación o una fecha. Sin embargo, si asumimos lo que decía antes, el `id` más alto representa el último precio, podrías obtener el `max(id)` por cada producto y luego obtener efectivamente el precio:

```
select  p.id_producto,
        pp.precio
        from producto p
        inner join  producto_precio pp
            on p.producto_id = pp.producto_id
        inner join (select  id_producto,
                            max(id) as ultimo_id,
                            from producto_precio
                            group by id_producto 
            ) m
            on  pp.id_producto = m.id_producto
            and pp.id = m.ultimo_id
```

Comment: disculpa eh tratado de entender tu consulta pero no lo he logrado, la "m" que representa?

Comment: Ya pude creare la consulta como esta escrita en tu respuesta pero solo me retorna el ultimo producto no la lista completa

Comment: La `m` que preguntas es un alias de tabla igual que `pp` o  `p`. No llego a ver como esta consulta retorne un solo producto, es que no tengo forma de probarla a menos que pongas un ejemplo de tus datos.

Comment: ya he editado para q veas el contenido de las tablas y el ejemplo de los datos q tienen, son tablas muy sencillas para hacer pruebas